# How to add a custom view in another custom view in Android?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I want to create a custom view which should be added in another custom view.

The second view will be a container, so it should be able to contain the first view as its child.

For creating this views I am extending `ViewGroup` & `LinearLayout` classes.

Child view class is ***NodeView***

```
public class NodeView extends LinearLayout
{
    private final static String TAG = "NodeView";
    private ImageView ivTop;
    private ImageView ivBottom;
    private Context myContext;

    public NodeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.myContext = context;

        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_test_multi, this, true);

        ivTop = (ImageView) getChildAt(0);
        ivBottom = (ImageView) getChildAt(2);

        ivTop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(myContext, "Top Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        ivBottom.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(myContext, "Bottom Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    public NodeView(Context context)
    {
        this(context, null);
    }
}
```

& the container class is ***TreeViewGroup***

```
public class TreeViewGroup extends ViewGroup
{
private static final String TAG = "CustomTreeNodeView";

NodeView nodeView;

public TreeViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    nodeView = new NodeView(getContext());
    addView(nodeView);
}

public TreeViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public TreeViewGroup(Context context)
{
    this(context, null, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
{
  }
}
```

& xml layout for node view is ***view_test_multi.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/point_grey" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/point_red" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/point_grey" />

</merge>
```

My activity's layout is ***activity_main.xml***

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.ab1209.testcustom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.ab1209.testcustom.view.TreeViewGroup
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_custom_tree_node_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

***MainActivity*** class is

```
**public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    TreeViewGroup treeNodeView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        treeNodeView = (TreeViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_custom_tree_node_view);
    }

}**
```

When I run the app I don't see the `NodeView` added in main View. Am I doing the right thing if not please tell me how can I make it working?

Comment: i do not understand, you just do `NodeView nodeView = new NodeView(context)`  then add it `treeNodeView.addView(nodeView ,params);` or did i misunderstand you, Sir?

Comment: try to give a height and width for the child view

Comment: @Elltz I think you are telling to do it in activity itself, I have tried that too but still no success.

Comment: @Krish I have also tried by giving height & width but no use.

Comment: @AB1209 Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To create a custom ViewGroup, the only method you need to override is
>   onLayout. The onLayout is triggered after the ViewGroup itself has
>   finished laying itself out inside its own container ViewGroup and is
>   now responsible for laying out its children. It should call the layout
>   method on all of its children to now position and size them (the left
>   and top parameters will determine the child view’s x and y and the
>   right and bottom will determine its width (right – left) and height
>   (top-bottom).

So your TreeViewGroup code will look like :

```
    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        int count = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {

                ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams) child
                        .getLayoutParams();

                int childLeft = 0;
                int childTop = 0;
                child.layout(childLeft, childTop,
                        childLeft + child.getMeasuredWidth(),
                        childTop + child.getMeasuredHeight());

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        measureChildren(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int measuredWidth = 200; // Calculate the height
        int measuredHeight = 200; // Calculate the width

        setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
    }
```

Refer this link http://arpitonline.com/2012/07/01/creating-custom-layouts-for-android/